# Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty php

Tags: php

I had asked this question and found out that the PHP configuration was limiting my uploads to 2MB, so I fixed it to 3MB. However, I have another problem now: I am also checking for image dimension and it is failing if the image appears to be over 3MB, throwing the below error. So how could I stop the error and check the size by myself instead of the PHP config?

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Here is the code:

```
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$minh = 400;
$minw = 600;
$one_MB = 1024*1024; //1MB
if($size > ($one_MB*3))// this is not checking the size at all, the last echo is what I get if I try to upload over 3mb.
{
  echo"File exceeds 3MB";
}
elseif ($width < $minw ) {
  echo "Image width shouldn't be less than 600px";
}
elseif ($height <  $minh){
  echo "Image height shouldn't be less than 400px";
}
else{
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_location)){
    //do something
  } 
  else{
    echo "Image is too big, try uploading below 3MB";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the upload went wrong at some point. Try adding some error handling before getimagesize():

```
if (!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "File upload failed. ";
    if (isset($_FILES['upfile']['error'])) {
         echo "Error code: ".$_FILES['upfile']['error'];
    }
    exit;
}
```

It's hard to say why it has failed, as there are many parameters involved. The Error code might give you a hint.

Otherwise maybe start reading here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I already tried same image with 1.5mb and it works and when I try 3.5 mb it fails so the reason why it is failing is because of the image size. What I don't understand is that why the first `if` statement isn't checking for the file size and letting the execution continue. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: You should check for the file size **before** you call get_image_size(). Your script is failing before you do any error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same error, go to php.ini and go to line 800 "upload_max_filesize".
Choose your max upload file size, i set mine to 4M and in my actual website code I dont allow anything after 3mb.
For some reason having them both the same size doesnt work, PHP.ini needs to be atleast 1mb bigger than what you allow to be uploaded.